# Remote service clean up, launcher screen refresh required

Tags: android

the problem is that once a widget of my application is uninstalled, it lkeaves a black message box on the home screen saying unable to load widget, i was wonderring if we could clean the system display our self, is it possbile to add some code/ call to instruct the android frame work to do that, the widget is being consumed by a remote service may be once service is finished/closed we can call some syetem calls, any code for helping out the home reloading will help, Thanks

Comment: i hope this is not closed like

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871546/reset-the-home-screen

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing for you to do. The user and the home screen will take care of this.

Comment: i have seen the behaviour of returning to Launch screen, from uninstalling the active widget, the launcher reloads it self, is it done by the framework or is  it a system call, let me digg up the application cant remember the name for which this behaviour was observed

Comment: @SoftReference: Nothing in your code gets executed when your application is uninstalled. It is physically impossible for you to do anything at that point in time. It is up to the home screen, or perhaps the user, to clean up.